# How to upload large number of variations in Configurable Product?

Tags: configurable-product, configurable-product-options

I am facing problem with large number of variations in **Configurable Product**. I am trying to add ring and it has around **384 variables, 24 sizes, 4 metal types and 4 color/clarity**.

This is the sample value for configurable_variations.

> https://gist.githubusercontent.com/samaybhavsar/43013064563c1fd6ce82cfb4f60b7bc8/raw/effb2e4f377077bc1891be78fb63e35f30d14b84/sample

When I try to upload. The upload happens successfully but the ring size does not show up in the product page.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Hey @Samay do all other variants options other then **`size`** are visible on front end means **`metal type`**, **`color/clarity`**? & do provide some image with your question

Comment: Yes. They are visible. What is the DB table which stores this ?

Comment: Product attribute related data is get stored in this tables in magento 2 `catalog_product_entity_int`, `catalog_product_index_eav_decimal`, `catalog_product_entity_varchar`, `catalog_product_entity_text`, `catalog_product_entity_media_gallery_value` depending on that which kind of data(type) it has

Comment: I strongly suggest that you are not making any changes through queries to those tables without understanding implications.  Keep in mind that flat tables have compiled these attributes for more efficient performance.  We save performance by cutting out the unions among EAV relations since queries now obtain and return data found in the flat tables.  Be sure to reindex if youve made changes but don't see them on the front-end.

Comment: Same here as @df2k2 said I just shared this to you for an information please do not do any changes to this tables through scripts

Comment: Thanks. This worked. There was some error creating the file.

Comment: Anyone help me, after i set configurable product, select dropdown value the price change to "0", may i know how can i solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

The data you have in the gist does not contain anything relating to ring sizes.  If you already knew that and were still asking for assistance with configurable products, then simply ensure that your `ring size` attribute is properly configured for front-end display, as well as configurable usage.  When you complete the creation of the attribute, ensure that you have assigned it to the proper attribute set.

If you have gotten that far, then creating simple products as children of the configurable, will require sizes to be specified per simple child.  One size = one simple product child.  10 sizes will ultimately be 10 simple products associated that parent configurable.